# How can I check if a browser blocks Canvas javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webp, brave

In an HTML website I'm checking `document.createElement('canvas').toDataURL('image/webp').indexOf('data:image/webp')` to determine whether the browser supports webp or not, and setting a class on the `<body>` so that CSS rules can be used to load image content in webp format if supported.

This tends to work fine, however on Brave iOS the fingerprinting blocking shield seems to prevent this script from running. I can't seem to get a developer console to inspect any error messages on Brave iOS, and `brave://inspect` seems to not work on Brave iOS like `chrome://inspect` works for Chrome iOS, so I haven't been able to see exactly what is happening. Desktop `brave://inspect` remote debugging seems to only support Android remote devices.

Curiously, Brave desktop with "fingerprinting blocked", even on a "strict, may break sites" level of aggression, doesn't seem to cause any problems, only on mobile.

When I toggle "block fingerprinting" on Brave iOS, my webp images disappear when blocked, and reappear when unblocked.

[This article on Brave fingerprinting blocking](https://brave.com/brave-fingerprinting-and-privacy-budgets/) states:

> Currently Brave protects against fingerprinting by preventing third party sites from accessing functionality frequently used to fingerprint users. This includes highly identifying parts of the Canvas, Web Audio and WebGL APIs, among others.

My theory is that is why my webp images are disappearing when fingerprinting is blocked, but I'm open to other ideas.

I'm wondering what exception is raised in such cases (if any), or how to gracefully detect such a scenario, but without a Brave iOS console to play in I'm flying blind.

I know I could check for Canvas *support*, but I'm not sure if "supported-but-blocked" is a different scenario.

Comment: You could start by adding a window error handler, that just writes all the error information to a textarea for you to inspect … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Comment: (_“to determine whether the browser supports webp or not”_ - have you looked into figuring that out on the server side, based on the `Accept` header the client sends?)

Comment: @CBroe will try both of those, thanks! Do you know if the `Accept` header is reliably sent containing `webp` by all supporting browsers?

Comment: You’d have to check, but I would assume it would make rather little sense for a browser vendor to go through the trouble of implementing it - and then not “advertising” it in the relevant places. Some browsers might only include it when making requests for actual images though (meaning, from the Accept header of the request that loaded your HTML document itself, you might not be able to tell - but the following requests for individual images should still contain the info then.)

Comment: Yes that was my concern, but if it's reliably available in non-image requests, that'd be great. Many browsers send `*/*` claiming they accept everything. I might need to keep the javascript as a fallback for browsers which don't explicitly specify `image/webp` in the `Accept` header.

Comment: Good to know, thanks @Kaiido - my source for this must have assumed the webp exporting and displaying capability would correlate, makes sense that they might not always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @CBroe's window error handler idea above, implemented as simply:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    window.alert([message, source, lineno, colno, error]);
};
```

I was able to ascertain that on Brave iOS with fingerprinting blocked, the Canvas element gets created successfully, and the `toDataURL` method does not raise an exception, but does return `undefined`.

So `(toDataURL('image/webp') || '')` gives me a reliable string to check for `data:image/webp` even when fingerprinting is blocked (though likely a false negative in those cases).

Furthermore, checking the `Accept` header on the main request can provide a shortcut -- if it explicitly contains `image/webp`, I can skip the javascript check altogether and set the body class on the server. Otherwise the javascript is a handy fallback, now more robust.

Thanks again @CBroe

Furthermore, @Kaiido's comment points out that the method of checking if the browser can *write* canvas contents to webp format may not necessarily correlate to the browser's ability to *display* webp images, so a [method which checks that specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220641/284164) is probably a better option